# Web2py auth.user object returns obsolete data

Tags: web2py

I am working on a web app that uses Web2py. My auth_user table has a username field. The problem that I am facing is when I update the username of a user, auth.user.username keeps returning the old value until the user logs out and login again.

Moreover sometimes I notice that even on making a fresh db query for the given user id it returns the obsolete user name. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auth.user` is stored in the session (along with some other auth related data). This avoids having to do a db query for the user data on every request. Therefore, updating the record in the db does not update the `auth.user` object in the session. If the user updates their own profile using the built in `auth.profile()` functionality, then `auth.user` will automatically get updated. Otherwise, you will have to update it yourself:

```
auth.user.update(username='my new name')
```

Comment: It's worth to mention that auth.user.update don't update the database.

Comment: Yes, perhaps that wasn't clear - assuming you have made the update in the db (as described in the question), you must *also* update the `auth.user` object.

Comment: Problem may happen when user has two sessions (ex. on two devices). Update db and auth.user on first device don't update auth.user on second device. In my app auth.user is always sync with db but this approach cause a db query.